# one header for some .c files leads to linker error

Tags: c, header, linker, makefile

My setup is like this:

```
src/
  dir1/
    header.h
    dir11
      (several files, every including header.h)
  dir2/
  (and so on)
```

But the linker tells me `undefined reference to (the function which is defined in the subdir "dir11")`. The header looks like this:

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h

/* some includes, all protected via ifndef-define-endif */

/* function prototypes for all functions in the 'dir11' subdir */
#endif // header_h
```

Makefile:

```
# some variables are defined before...

TARGET=mytarget 
SOURCES= ${shell find ${SRC} -type f -name '*.c'} 
OBJECTS=${foreach x, $(basename $(SOURCES)), $(x).o}

compile: ${OBJECTS}

%.o: %.c 
        ${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} ${HEADERS} $^ -o $@

link:
        ${LD} ${OBJECTS} -o ${TARGET}
```

How to resolve this? Writing headers for every file in the subdir is the last way I want to go, because there are ~50 files in it!

EDIT:
Maybe this is useful: The header.h is also included elsewere to call the functions! Do I have to declare this functions as `extern` when including elsewere?

Comment: "undefined reference to"... to *what*? And I'm hoping thats a typo and you meant **`#ifndef`** at the top of that header file. A `#ifdef` would be a little pointless (and prevent anything from being included within).

Comment: is your include guard wrong? shouldn't it read `#ifndef header_h`?

Comment: well yes, that was a typo. Undefined reference to the functions, which are defined in the `.c` files in the subdirectory. (I'll edit this in the question post!)

Comment: So its an undefined reference, not an un**resolved** reference at link? If compile-time, you're *not* getting cannot-find-include-file "blah" compilation errors? Also, what does the magic ${HEADERS} macro expand to?

Comment: The headers macro expands to `-I./src`. Compilation works without errors (except some -Wunused-function warnings)!

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, any explanations for it?

Answer (score 0):

Are all your include guard defines different? If not you will get undefined reference warnings/errors depending on your compiler settings

Comment: Yes, they are. Always `__<projectname>_<filename>_H__`!

Comment: Just make sure that your header files do not have the same name

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote? They _are_ different in each file!

Comment: Sorry, just trying to find your problem.